# Invitation email doesn't have a From: value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

When I invite an user, the email with the inviation link gets sent successfully.
However, the email has no `From:` value, so the mail server returns an error because it (rightfully) refuses to send an email without a `From` value.

So I need to set that value somewhere, but I don't know where and how?
Both `devise` and `devise_invitable` do not create an `UserMailer` or `InvitationMailer` object.
This is my `invite` method:

```
  def invite
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    user.update_attributes(invitation_created_at: DateTime.now)
    user.deliver_invitation

    redirect_to users_path, notice: I18n.t("user.messages.invited")
  end
```

How can I make sure the `From` value gets filled?

Comment: Are you using `DeviseMailer` or `ActionMailer`? And also post the Mailer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For devise add email address to `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.mailer_sender = 'Me <noreply@me.com>'
```

For ActionMailer add config to environment config file, e.g. `config/environments/production.rb`

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'Me <noreply@me.com>'
```

You can also overwrite these on per mailer basis:

```
class ExampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Me <ceo@me.com>"
```

Answer (score 1):

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, you can add

```
config.mailer_sender = 'Name <noreply@gmail.com>'
```

Hope it helps you!